# General term for a technique that ensures that two parts can be mated only if they are meant to be mated, and prevent any other part from mating

Tags: mechanical-engineering, terminology

I am looking for the general term for any technique used to make sure that two parts can be mated only if they are meant to be mated, and prevent any other parts from mating.

I need this term as I describe characteristics of electrical connectors. But I am looking for the mechanical term for these techniques, not an electrical term.

This is what I have:

- Polarization: forces you to mate the correct mates in the correct orientation; keeps you from mating them in the wrong orientation; e.g., plugging a polarized plug into an AC power outlet turned 180 degrees
- xxx: matches the shape and dimensions of two **parts** (not assemblies) so they fit together perfectly and other parts won't fit. e.g., the differences between an EU AC power plug and a US AC power plug
- Keying: slight modifications in otherwise identical plugs so that they can only be plugged into the correct receptacles; e.g., removing a pin from a PCB header and blocking the corresponding hole in the plug

I am looking for the proper term for "xxx".

Thank you.

EDIT: best suggestions so far include "conforming", "pairing", "congruence", "fitting".

EDIT: Not "poke-yoke": that's design for mistake-proofing the manufacturing process.

Comment: can it be "mateable"? :)

Comment: unique ........

Comment: Have a look at the Japanese [poka-yoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poka-yoke). This term is well understood in western manufacturing practices.

Comment: I am well aware of poka-yoke and many have suggested it. Thank you, but that's not the word. poka-yoke refers to making an assembly fool-proof. I am not asking to make an _assembly_ fool proof. I am asking about making two _parts_ match and fit each other perfectly.

Comment: attaching two parts is an assembly

Comment: "attaching two parts is an assembly". Yes. And? I said " I am asking about making two parts match and fit each other perfectly. " Fit, not attach.

Comment: How about Paired?

Comment: "Paired". Yes, thank you. As you can see, I had "pairing" in my list of suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

"Conforming"

Thank you all.

It's now in the book.

#### 2.6.6  Polarization, conforming, and keying

Polarization, conforming, and keying are three technologies that ensure that two mating parts fit perfectly. Where they differ is in what they prevent from mating:

- Polarization: prevents mating the correct parts in the incorrect orientation (fig. 2.109a)
- Conforming: prevents mating the incorrect parts (fig. 2.109b)
- Keying: prevents mating to a nearly-identical part that must be mated elsewhere  (fig. 2.109c)

[image: Book screen shot]

Comment: While I don't have a problem with any of those terms, the term I use in practice is "clocking".

Comment: Clocking? In what sense? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/clocking

Comment: https://www.interconnect-wiring.com/aerospace/what-is-connector-clocking-and-why-is-it-important-in-wiring-harness-design/

Comment: Ah! Now I understand. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, that article conflates "keying" and "polarization". Clocking is one of the many possible ways to perform "keying", not "polarization".